# How do I set the env variables properly so I can run Blender with customized paths on Windows?

Tags: scripting, add-on, windows

I want to run a customized version of Blender on Windows. So i set these env variables in  a batch file. Blender picks up the user config folder alright but it still points to default addon paths when it comes to scripts.

```
SET BLENDER_USER_CONFIG=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79_RELEASE\config

SET BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79_RELEASE\scripts

SET BLENDER_USER_DATAFILES=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79_RELEASE\datafiles

cd C:\BLENDER_RELEASE

cmd /c blender.exe
```

thanks

Comment: This isn't really a question about blender. https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them?noredirect=1&lq=1 has a how to.

Comment: How is that not a question about Blender? As I said, Blender is not recognizing the scripts paths but it does with config path. Both are set  the exact same way in the batch file. I already put my batch file, not asking how I can use env variables.

Comment: Fair point.  Because of how env variables work, I would suspect that either you've encountered a (rare) bug in blender, or, more likely, the variable you want either doesn't exist, is spelled differently, or has been over ridden